# How to reconnect / retrieve realtime session of previous jupyter notebook session?

Tags: python, websocket, jupyter-notebook

I have so much data to process and that takes a lot of time. Closing the tab of jupyter session disconnects the existing realtime session and output, so I can't retrieve previous realtime result. Example:  I want to get `tqdm` progress shown again after I reopen the closed tab of jupyter. I want to retrieve the realtime session and get the realtime feedback again.

I did some research about this but it didn't seek about the realtime.

Any solution to this?

Comment: Generally, Jupyter isn't best for long computation. You are better off running scripts while attached to a command line session with screen, tmux, or a modern version of such a tool and then detaching while it runs and return later. Then you re-attach later. That being said, there has been work to address that in Jupyter, see [here](https://twitter.com/KyleRayKelley/status/1647439683759280133) and [here](https://twitter.com/HamelHusain/status/1643663336285040640) for advanced options.

Comment: Ok then, I will consider that tool @Wayne