# Show the outputs in Jupyter Notebook running on AWS EC2

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-ec2, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am training my ASR based attention model on AWS EC2 (g4dn.xlarge) and use Jupyter Notebook to run my code on the EC2 instance. I selected DeepLearning AMI during my instance creation so all the ML/DL packages are pre-installed.

To run my code, I establish ssh with instance and then create a new screen in which I launch Jupyter Notebook server. Here is my terminal code.

```
~ ssh -i "key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-xxxx-x.compute.amazonaws.com -L 8888:localhost:8888
~ screen
~ source activate pytorch
~ jupyter notebook
```

However, if I close my laptop or my laptop goes to sleep for an extended duration (I beleive more than 15 mins), my connection with AWS instance is disconnected and I get a Broken Pipe message.

```
[I 23:07:03.002 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for ba0151b2-d4cb-4b85-a30b-692378ec8232:78dc6026e4fc47318cd3fbf3d7ae2ccf
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

Even after establishing my connection back and refreshing my notebook, I am never able to see the cell outputs. This is despite the fact that once I connect back, I get replaying buffered messages before it being discarded.

```
[I 06:37:31.683 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for bd6f4e02-2b9d-4e42-acca-50f2487efb5c:1d73df5117f648078c0f4dcc72f20ff8
[I 06:37:33.857 NotebookApp] Discarding 3481 buffered messages for bd6f4e02-2b9d-4e42-acca-50f2487efb5c:1d73df5117f648078c0f4dcc72f20ff8
```

How can I ensure that whenever I re-ssh back to my EC2 instance, my jupyter notebook syncs and has all the outputs of the cell. Thanks a lot for answering my question.

I am expecting that whenever I re-ssh, I can get back to see my output cells. This is especially important if I am training a large model and want to monitor its progress.

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be to use a session manager such as `tmux`, which will allow you to reattach to the session and see the outputs even after disconnecting. There are plenty of guides online for installing and using tmux.

This is a nice friendly article: https://linuxize.com/post/getting-started-with-tmux/

Comment: In line with this great reply, see [my comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76141615/how-to-reconnect-retrieve-realtime-session-of-previous-jupyter-notebook-sessio?noredirect=1#comment134279920_76141615). In particular, I mention some advanced options out there.